# Why is the pinned content of my scrolltrigger disappearing (Locomotive Scroll)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gsap, locomotive-scroll, scrolltrigger

My slider component disappears when it should pin to the page. I believe it is related to the page scroll with Locomotive scroll messing up with translating the page. However, this should be possible and I found a tutorial by Greensock. I cannot get it to work though, my content keeps disappearing. Here is a minimal demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-noyce-108h6c?file=/pages/index.tsx

Here is also a link to the final webpage: https://juliaweber-git-preview-inzn.vercel.app

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Greensock Demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/ExPdqKy)